# How does one actually use Markdown with Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, markdown, showdown

I'm working on a project with Meteor, and I want it to use markdown, and it was very nice to see that there is a package to do that with.

So I meteor added showdown, it worked, and now I can do something like

```
{{#markdown}}
    #This is a header

    this is a paragraph
{{/markdown}}
```

and it works just fine. But now I want to actually put something more interesting in there. First thought was to sync it up with a textarea. I tried three things. First, I tried this:

```
$('.preview').html('{{#markdown}}'+$('#text').val()+'{{/markdown}}');
```

Where .preview is a div that I want to html to show up in, and #text is the textarea where someone is typing. This doesn't work though, it just shows the {{#markdown}} and stuff.

Next, I tried to just set up the div like this:

```
<div class="preview">
    {{#markdown}}

    {{/markdown}}
</div>
```

And add to it with:

```
$('.preview').html('#Is this an H1?');
```

or

```
$('.preview').append('*is this italics?*');
```

But again, it just showed the text, not the html.

Finally, I tried hard coding stuff into the markdown section, but that just clearly didn't work. Things like

```
<div class="preview">
    {{#markdown}}
        <div class="previewInner">

        </div>
    {{/markdown}}
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="span6 preview">
    {{#markdown}}
        {{>innerPreview}}
    {{/markdown}}
</div>
```

So basically, I've tried everything I can think of and none of it does what I want. I tried I few more things, but I think you get the idea. How am I supposed to use this?

> It's easy: just put your markdown inside {{#markdown}} ... {{/markdown}} tags.

Comment: I use markdown in http://superchat.meteor.com/ but with the package marked. It's the same syntax. Just take a look at the code: https://github.com/gabrielhpugliese/meteor_superchat/blob/master/client/views/chatroom.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything inside markdown is considered markdown so make sure you do this:

```
{{#markdown}}{{>innerPreview}}{{/markdown}}
```

Instead of

```
{{#markdown}}
    {{>innerPreview}}
{{/markdown}}
```

The jquery wouldn't work because `{{markdown}}` is rendered before the DOM is put in place.

Instead use a session

```
Template.hello.markdown_data = function() {return Session.get("markdown_data")});
```

Then your template

```
{{#markdown}}{{{markdown_data}}}{{/markdown}}
```

Then store your markdown document in

`Session.set("markdown_data","<your markdown data>");`

Comment: Great, this has got it working more like expected. Except I can't get it to make blockquotes. Does Showdown have everything from http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax ?

Comment: @user1624005 probably not (github doesn't), no harm raising a pull request if you want it.

Comment: You can use the markdown package named marked. It seems to have support for blockquotes. It is on atmosphere: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/marked