# How do I generate and download a PDF from markdown using Meteor

Tags: pdf, meteor, markdown

I have a Meteor collection of documents whose content is styled using [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (for an example of how to do this please see: [How does one actually use Markdown with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030896/776476))

My package stack is as follows:

**npm**

- [markdown-pdf](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf)
- [sanitize-filename](https://github.com/parshap/node-sanitize-filename)

**Atmosphere**

- [coffeescript](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/coffeescript)
- [iron-router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router)

When viewing a document I would like to present my users with a `Download as PDF` button. Clicking on this should convert the document's markdown to a PDF file and download it via the browser.

The conversion process is constrained; it should run on the server but is not allowed to save any temporary files to the server.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `iron-router`, create a server-side route to serve up the PDF.

```
Router.route '/api/pdf/:_id',
    name : 'generatePDF'
    where: 'server'
    action: ->
        document= Documents.findOne @params._id
        sanitize = Meteor.npmRequire 'sanitize-filename'
        filename = sanitize(document.title).replace(/\s+/g, '-')
        @response.writeHead 200,
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=#{filename}.pdf"

        markdown = document.content
        Async.runSync (done)->
            Meteor.npmRequire('markdown-pdf')
            .from.string(markdown)
            .to.buffer (err, buffer)->
                done null, new BufferStream buffer
        .result.pipe @response
```

The route above receives an `_id` as a route parameter. This is used to retrieve the associated `document` from the `Documents` collection. The PDF `filename` is then generated by sanitizing the `document.title` replacing all spaces with hyphens.

The response headers are now set to force the browser to download the PDF as a file with the sanitized `filename`.

The PDF is generated from the `document.content` markdown using the `markdown-pdf` package. This process is complicated by two issues:

1. The call to generate the PDF is intrinsically asynchronous and therefore requires a callback. This needs to be converted to a synchronous call by wrapping it in Meteor's `Async.runSynch` method. This returns an object with a `result` property we can use.
2. The `markdown-pdf` package has a `to.buffer` method that returns a `buffer` containing the generated PDF. This allows us to keep everything in code and removes any need to save a temporary file to the server. To pipe this `buffer` into the `response` we need to convert it to a stream. I use a helper `BufferStream` object to do this for me (see below)

With this route in place I just need to place a 'Download as PDF' button somewhere on my display template (the code below is a Jade link styled as a button by Bootstrap 3 classes)

```
a.btn.btn-primary(href='{{pathFor "generatePDF"}}' target='_blank') Download as PDF
```

And finally, here is that `BufferStream` helper class:

```
stream = Meteor.npmRequire "stream" 

class @BufferStream extends stream.Readable 

    constructor: (@source, @offset = 0) ->
        throw new Meteor.Error 'InvalidBuffer', 'BufferStream source must be a buffer.' unless Buffer.isBuffer(@source)
        super
        @length = @source.length

    _read: (size) ->
        if @offset < @length
            @push @source.slice @offset, @offset + size
            @offset += size

        @push null if @offset >= @length
```